# Cannot get clothing physics to work in animation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a character wearing a tunic with cloth physics applied. The upper part of the tunic is pinned so I can animate that manually, its only the bottom part with clothing physics applied so it can interact with my characters legs. Now I've rigged and am animating my character, and the bottom of the tunic is animating with cloth physics but it is not "moving with" the body that has a collider set on it. It just stays there in place while the rest of the rig clips through it.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Hopefully this makes sense or I can post pcs.

Comment: parent the cloth to the armature with automatic weights, also see this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg